# Less quit behavior

Tags: terminal, less, exit, vi

I'm not sure how to describe this but I'll try by comparing it to vi. When I open vi, do something, and then exit vi it brings me back to the terminal where I can see all of the commands I had previously executed.

Is there a way that I can get less to to behave similarly instead of seeing the lines of the file I had just viewed? Preferably a command so that I can decide at the last minute.

Thanks,
Gregg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`less -X` might be what you're looking for, that's the option to disable preserving and resetting the screen

It could be that you're sending some less options by default. Do you have `$LESS` defined in your environment?

`less -+X` will reset the option, you could try calling it like that and see if it helps.

Comment: I didn't realize it, but I did have a less environment. Once I found where it was set and commented it out it works as expected. I've played around with the -X stuff but it's not clear to me whether it was the cause. My LESS variable was set to: --no-init --clear-screen --LONG-PROMPT --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS --shift 5 --buffers=8192

Comment: cool! Yeah, I wasn't sure about -X +-X I just picked one that I know affects screen resets and saves to use as an example